# How to force text down in table-header?

Tags: tables

I would like to have my table-headers in the bottom of the cell, instead of in the top, as they are in this piece of code.
Can anybody help me?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
enter\begin{table}[h]
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\normalsize
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
       \captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}  
  \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{2pt plus 5pt minus 1pt}
     \caption{Fertilitetsmål og antal kvinder i den fødedygtige alder (15-49 år)}  
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm} p{3cm} p{3cm} p{3cm} p{3cm}}
  \toprule[1.5pt]

& Levendefødte & Summarisk fertilitetskvotient & Generel fertilitetskvotient & Kvinder i fødedygtig alder (15-49 år) \\
\midrule
1994 & 69666 & 13,4 & 53,4 & 1.305.101 \\
1995 & 69771 & 13,4 & 53,8 & 1.297.730 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption*{Kilde: NAT03}
\label{tab:Disponibel indkomst}
\end{threeparttable}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.50}\normalsize
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: That should do it - thank you, for the advice!

Comment: Your code still does not compile, as is.  You are missing some package definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this code correspond to what you want? I must say I didn't understand why you have two captions – I supposed you meant a table note (hence the use of threeparttable).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{threeparttable, caption, booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage[textwidth = 16cm, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}

\begin{document}
Enter

   \begin{table}[h]
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}\normalsize\centering
   \begin{threeparttable}
   \captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false,position = below}
   \begin{tabular}{*{5}{r}}
   \toprule
       & \makecell[cb]{Levendefødte} & \makecell[cb]{Summarisk \\ fertilitetskvotient} 
       & \makecell[cb]{Generel \\ fertilitetskvotient} & \makecell[cb]{Kvinder i fødedygtig  \\    alder (15-49 år)} \\  
   \midrule
       1994 & 69666 & 13,4 & 53,4 & 1.305.101 \\
       1995 & 69771 & 13,4 & 53,8 & 1.297.730 \\
   \bottomrule[1.5pt]
   \end{tabular}
   \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
       \item  Kilde: NAT03
   \end{tablenotes}
   \caption{Fertilitetsmål og antal kvinder i den fødedygtige alder (15-49 år)}
   \label{tab:Disponibel indkomst}
   \end{threeparttable}
   \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: which results in]

Comment: Wow. That is actually perfect. But it is possible to align the numbers to the right, keeping the header where it is?

Comment: Here you are, Mylord. I modified the answer. One just had to replace *{5}{c} with *{5}{r} in the preamble of the table.

Comment: Modified: I had forgotten the headers had to be bottom-aligned